# Can't authenticate with exchange server

Tags: email, evolution, ms-exchange, evolution-mapi

I'm using Evolution with `evolution-mapi` to access an Exchange e-mail server.
It has worked flawlessly in the past, but recently it will fail to authenticate, asking my password endlessly. If I enter the correct password, it tells me that it is incorrect.
If I enter an incorrect password, it closes the prompt, but fails to obtain the mail from the inbox (due to the truly incorrect password).

EDIT: I fixed part of the issue by pointing my client to the server's IP address rather than its hostname, but it will still occasionally fail to send/receive e-mail.